# How to get used range in .net core by using NPOI

Tags: c#, .net-core, npoi

I'm using NPOI in my .net core library to do some operations in my excel sheet.

I'm now want to get the used rang in the worksheet. Is there any way to achieve this target? For some reasons, I cannot use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` COM component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this question by using the `LastRowNum` and `LastCellNum` property.

For example, If I have got a ISheet instance like the following:

`var sheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(0);`

Then, I can get the range by the `LastRowNum` and `LastCellNum` property.

```
var row = sheet.LastRowNum;
var column = sheet.GetRow(row).LastCellNum;
var range = new { row, column };
```